# Why my code fails to draw frame around "standalone" document using "current page" node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, border, current-page

I am trying to draw a frame around a document but output is not what I expected.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[draw,line width=1mm]
(current page.north east)rectangle(current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: standalone makes a page with the size of the content. `overlay` makes a picture with no size. `current page` is reference to the current page. The combination of all this makes my head spin.

Comment: It works if you just use the `article` class. You can always adjust the size of the page with package `geometry`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - interesting background.

Comment: I a `standalone` context, I would think `current bounding box` (used at the very end of the `tikzpicture`) would be more appropriate than `current page`. Without `overlay` of course, which makes a zero sized bounding box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TikZ` can do this job for you with `backgrounds` library and `framed` option for tikzpicture.

`Backgrounds` library can be used to draw a frame or grid around/behind particular `scopes` or the whole `tikzpicture`. You can define a `background rectangle` style and fix the distance between tikzpicture (`current bounding box`) limits and desired frame with `inner frame {x|y}sep` option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{
    background rectangle/.style={
        draw=red,
        line width=1mm
    }
} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed, inner frame sep=1cm]
        \path node {hello world};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Torbjørn T. suggested, I now use `current bounding box` at the end of `tikzpicture`. Also, `border` option should be removed from `standalone` class unless you want some space between document bounds and your frame.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\MARGIN}{10mm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node{hello world};
        \path[draw,line width=1mm]
            ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-\MARGIN,\MARGIN)$)
            rectangle
            ($(current bounding box.south east)+(\MARGIN,-\MARGIN)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]